# Where can I find used controls in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delphi

I want to switch to C# from Delphi.

But the problem is Visual Studio has very different design from Delphi IDE.

In "Structure" menu, I can see controls used in my form like this:

[image]

Is there any Visual Studio equivalent of this menu?

Comment: Solution Explorer is done like that. That representation (tree nodes) is quite common among all IDEs

Comment: Are you looking for the _visual_ structure of a form or the _syntactical_ structure? Unfortunately, your screenshot shows names in a language I don't understand, so I cannot tell what it is.

Comment: @PMF Yes, I am looking for the tree structure of the form. And that screenshot is taken from Delphi IDE. "p_" is panel, "lbl_" is label and "i_" is image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, in the Windows Forms App project type in Visual Studio, you want to see the controls used in the form in a menu.

First you need to create a Windows Forms App.

**You can then use the Solution Explorer to view the form and the controls used in the form**. As shown below, I put two buttons on Form1:

[image]

If you don't find Solution Explorer, you can find it by following these steps:

View => Solution Explorer

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is basically what I want. As I understand, C# is too much different from Delphi. And lot harder too.

Comment: I'd say C# is quite similar to Delphi (more so than most other modern languages), and not harder at all.